# Find Youtube Channel by Custom URL

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

Recently I am trying to collect Youtube channel infos by urls. With Youtube API V3 youtube.channels.list, I can get channels by below two types of urls with no problem. 
https://www.youtube.com/user/LadyGagaVEVO/ (query by forUserName)
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC07Kxew-cMIaykMOkzqHtBQ (query by id)

However for the custom url such as 
https://www.youtube.com/phunky
I found no official way to get the channel. I know it is possible to get the channel by parsing OpenGraph meta-data. Still want to know if there is more ideal way with the V3 API.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I've seen is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37947865/revisions) which is to use the search api. It's not perfect but it is the only solution I've seen.

Comment: It doesn't work because it might return multiple channels in search results.